# How can I use image form json response using angularjs?

Tags: json, angularjs

I have api which return image corresponsding to the userID.

**API code whcih return image:**

```
public function getImage($id) {
        if(File::exists('uploads/'.$id.'.jpg')) {
            $image = File::get('uploads/'.$id.'.jpg');
            return Response::make($image, 200, array('content-type' => 'image/jpg'));
        } else {
            return Response::json(array('error'=>true,'details'=>'No image.'));
        }

}
```

Route to get image is **"api/image/id"**

**AngularJS Code:**

```
QAApp.controller('imgCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

      $scope.image = function (id) {
             $http({
                              method: 'GET', 
                              url: server + 'api/image/' + id,
                            }).success(function(data){
                              console.log(data);
                             $scope.imageUrl= data; // if you sure what data is you URL 
                       })
              }
          });
```

**HTML Code :**

```
<div class="artst-pic pull-left" ng-controller="imgCtrl">
       <img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" ng-init="image(q.userID)" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
 </div>
```

If I give the api path with server path then I get the image but if I am using that api  path in angularsjs code,  I didnt get image, I an getting the response like that:

**�ޑ�����b���[����T��Ԏ�����{����O���Q(�b'��ձ�3]Ӵ������ۯ��I�`�U+��=>���i�C�~o`�����/2fh�*������]Y�]�ƅ���ԋ��ʋj�ў��**

I dont know why this is happen, please tell me if anybody know about this.

Comment: what you are getting back is actual image rather than its url. just specify image path in `ng-src` rather than getting back the actual image.

Comment: when I use "http://localhost:8000/api/image/7" directly on browser then I am getting image, and same if use it in my angularjs code, it will return the response that I have post.I dont know how can I get the image url, please see my code and tell where I am going wrong....

Comment: just try it by changing to below code `<img ng-src="/folder-having-images/image.jpg"`. so what you need in ng-src is the path of the file and not the image. e.g. `ng-src="/uploads/7.jpg"` you dont need the $http call.

Comment: But I didn't have are folder for image, I have to takeen it form server directly....Is there any method that I can use image directly which is return by api, othervise I have to write the code to download that image and save in a folder and then by using ng-src use the image..........

Comment: i am talking about server folder path... not client. what i understand from your code is: uploads/7.jpg must be the file path

Comment: That upload folder is not in database, that folder is in laravel API folder, means I have two seprate folder one is for API which is written using laravePHP and I start the server form laravelAPI folder and use that url of server for my code which is in another folder...and that upload folder is in laravelApi folder not in my folder. So how can I accsee that folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and in your html

```
<div class="artst-pic pull-left" ng-controller="imgCtrl">
       <img ng-src="uploads/{{q.UserID}}.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
 </div>
```

and remove the function from controller...

Comment: that does not need to be in database... files can be worked out from filesystem...

Comment: yes i tried but not getting image because I did'nt have that folder in my directive.....it is not possible with api call..because that api return image directly....

Comment: then you can change the api to return the path rather than image

Answer (score 1):

Like **HarishR** said **"function getImage($id)"** should return the path not the image, 
In your case it will return something like - **/uploads/id.jpg**

Though you do not need to make an api call if your code is storing all images in uploads folder with the name of a userId